# Check if there is an error handler on observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to check if there was an error handler provided by the observer of an observable.

The reason I want this is because I want to have the following use case:

- If the observer provided an error handler, use it when an error is thrown
- Otherwise, if no error handler was provided by the observer, use a default error handling logic

The only way to achieve that is by knowing whether or not an error handler was provided (unless there is another way I'm missing).

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
foo = Observable.from([...]).catch((err, selector) => {
    // Do something...
});

foo.subscribe(
    () => console.log('Success'),
    () => console.log('Error'),
    () => console.log('Finally'),
);
```

What I want to do is, within the first block where the "Do something" comment is, I want to check if the observer subscribing to the stream has provided an error handler, which is this part:

```
// ...
() => console.log('Error'),
// ...
```

I've tried to access the properties inside the `selector`, like so:

```
foo = Observable.from([...]).catch((err, selector) => {
    console.log(selector);
});
```

...but it's not obvious which one of those properties (or their deeply nested child properties) represent the error handler the observer provided.

Is this information even possible to retrieve from within an observable? I imagine the handler has to be stored *somewhere*, otherwise how would it be triggered for an observer when an error is thrown?

Nothing on the RxJS docs seems to explain how to retrieve the error handler that was set by the observer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some pseudocode of the big picture of what I'd like to achieve:

```
foo = Observable.from([...]).catch((err, selector) => {
    if (selector.catch) {
        return Observable.throw(err)
    } else {
        // Do something else to handle the error, but don't throw anymore since the observer isn't listening for an error.
        console.log('Doing something else...');
        return Observable.empty();
    }
});

// On error, "Error" will be logged
foo.subscribe(
    () => console.log('Success'),
    () => console.log('Error'),
    () => console.log('Finally'),
);

// On error, "Doing something else..." will be logged
foo.subscribe(
    () => console.log('Success')
);
```

Comment: Observables have no idea who is listening, you'll need to restructure your approach or use some sort of a helper.

Comment: But isn't the `selector` the observer? It says in the source code for `.catch()`: `"{function} selector a function that takes as arguments 'err', which is the error, and 'caught', which is the source observable, in case you'd like to "retry" that observable by returning it again."` Wouldn't the "source" be the observer in this case, or am I misinterpreting that?

Comment: `selector` is the **function** passed to `catch()` in the documentation.  In your code, `selector` is actually `caught` per the documentation.  `catch` is not provided the observer.

Comment: Ah I see..so basically this is not possible with the raw RxJS without modifying it or adding a wrapper with custom logic or something like that... Hmm. It sure would be nice if the observable knew who was observing it.

Comment: @Lansana It took me a while to find it, but you can read more about this design logic, pro & con arguments, and more, under [this Github issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2312).

Comment: @Nit Thanks for the link! Very informative, but doesn't solve this problem unfortunately. Given that an Observable does not contain pointers to it's observers, I suppose the only solution is by creating a custom wrapper to keep track of things. This seems like a poor solution to me. It's intuitive to be able to have the context of an observer for each iteration within the observable itself, maybe passed in one of the pipeline callbacks or something along those lines, in the same way you get the iteratee of a loop in your callback when you use `Array.forEach(...)`, etc.